# React Router Crashing After Certain Routes

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm writing a web-app with React and React Router Dom. Certain Routes crash the Router; everything in Switch stops working during a crash.

Under the following conditions the Switch crashes:

- The URL in set to the search page then the search page will work, but after switching to any other route Switch has appeared to crash.
- If a non-sense URL is given and is then corrected to a real path in the app, then the changed correct path does not allow Switch to update.

The area that appears to crash is only the components that are wrapped in the Switch. All the elements outside the switch keep rendering on all routes. The desired behaviour is then when a non-sense route nothing will be render by Switch, but changing to a valid path will continue to work. After navigating to Search subsequently chosen valid paths will also continue to work. Working is defined by the Switch statement displays the appropriate component defined in routes.

### package.json

```json
{
    "name": "app1",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
        "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
        "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
        "elasticlunr": "^0.9.5",
        "mark.js": "^8.11.1",
        "react": "^17.0.2",
        "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
        "react-router-dom": "^5.3.0",
        "react-scripts": "^3.4.4",
        "react-serialize": "^0.2.0",
        "theme": "file:../theme",
        "web-vitals": "^1.1.2"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "purge-install": "rm -rf node_modules/ package-lock.json && npm install --force",
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject"
    },
    "eslintConfig": {
        "extends": [
            "react-app",
            "react-app/jest"
        ]
    },
    "browserslist": {
        "production": [
            ">0.2%",
            "not dead",
            "not op_mini all"
        ],
        "development": [
            "last 1 chrome version",
            "last 1 firefox version",
            "last 1 safari version"
        ]
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0"
    }
}
```

### Source Code with Switch

```js
import React from 'react';
import * as RRD from 'react-router-dom';

import './oldtheme/FontAwesome/css/font-awesome.min.css';
import './oldtheme/ayu-highlight.css';
import './css/chrome.css';
import './css/general.css';
import './css/variables.css';
import './oldtheme/fonts/fonts.css';
import './oldtheme/highlight.css';

import { html } from './utils.js';
import PageHeader from './page-header.js';
import Page from './page.js';
import Search from './search/index.js';
import TOC from './toc.js';


/** The entry point to start the book */
export default function Book(props)
{
    // html().classList.add("light")
    html().classList.add("js");
    html().classList.add("sidebar-visible");

    document.title = props.book_title;
    return (
    <RRD.BrowserRouter>
        <TOC chapters={props.source.sections()}/>
        <div id="page-wrapper" class="page-wrapper">
            <div class="page">
        <PageHeader searchable={props.searchable}
                title={props.book_title}/>
                <RRD.Switch>
            <RRD.Route path="/search">
            <Search/>
                    </RRD.Route>
            <RRD.Route exact path="/">
            <RRD.Redirect to="/pages/cover"/>
                    </RRD.Route>
                    <RRD.Route path="/pages/:section">
            <Page source={props.source}/>
                    </RRD.Route>
                </RRD.Switch>
            </div>
        </div>
    </RRD.BrowserRouter>
    );
}
```

Comment: `href` isn't a valid React component, so at a minimum you are not following React component naming and rendering conventions and breaking the rules of hooks for the `useHistory` hook. Also the `Route` component prop is supposed to take a reference to a React component, not an anonymous function to return JSX, this will actually remount the component each time instead of rerendering anything. Overall, the code is a little convoluted, I'm not surprised it's crashing. What is `href` supposed to be, a utility function? As a "component" it's not returning anything to render.

Comment: @DrewReese thanks. I'll change it. Will the change fix the problem in the question?

Comment: Unlikely. Is it still crashing? Are there any errors? What debugging have you done? Is it possible to create a *running* codesandbox that reproduces this issue that we can inspect and debug live?